# How to troubleshoot "disappearing" jQuery validation in Angular appliacation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

We have this Angular (1.2.19) page which utlizes the jQuery validation library for form validation. Sometimes all validation functionality disappears:  people can just submit whatever they want and nothing is validated. This behaviour occurs perhaps 50% of the time and otherwise works fine. No errors present in the console.

Our current theory is that this might have something to do with the order that javascript files are loaded, and that sometimes the are loaded in an order that creates conflict but not sure how to verify this since no errors show up?

Here's our index file script

```
<!-- JQUERY -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/userjs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/userjs/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/extra-validator-methods.js"></script>

<!-- ANGULAR CORE JS -->
<script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-qr/lib/qrcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-qr/angular-qr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-validate/angular-validate.js"></script>
```

Comment: And can you reproduce it with opened browser debugger ? to see in `console` what error in case of none validation you have ?

Answer (score 1):

The order of the scripts is not the issue; they're loading in the same order every time (they're blocking includes).

More likely, Angular is removing the `<form>` from the DOM and injecting a new one after $digest propagates a change to one of the form's parent nodes. When the jQuery plugin ran the first time, it attached handlers to the `<input>` nodes; but those inputs got removed and replaced with new ones, so the keypress/change/submit events aren't triggering the jQuery handlers.

It's best to use Angular event handlers (like `ng-change`, `ng-submit`, etc.) to validate the inputs from within an Angular controller. Trying to manage the state of the form with both Angular and jQuery will be a drag.

Use `ng-model` to track each field in your controller, and on `ng-change`, check their values and provide feedback.